# Change role in maintenance mode

Tags: user-roles, maintenance

I'm using https://de.wordpress.org/plugins/wp-maintenance-mode/ . 
I need to test the wp-admin page with different user roles while in maintenance mode. When I switch to a different role than admin the maintenance screen shows up.

Is there a way to test the wp-admin page with a different role while in maintenance mode?

Answer (score 0):

Login as admin to my-wordpress-site/wp-admin.
Go to Plugins -> WP Maintenance Mode -> Settings.
Add a role to Backend Roles.

[image]

To create a new role for maintenance use https://wordpress.org/plugins/user-role-editor/. User Role editor can create copies of existing roles.